# Markov property in time series

Tags: time-series, markov-process

I work on some time series which are 1Hz. I have three questions about them:

1. How can I test Markov property on time series?
2. If Markov property doesn't hold, Is it possible to downsample time series to Markov property holds?
3. If the answer of 2 is yes, How is possible to choose a good frequency for downsampling?

Actually I want to know about practical methods. [This](https://hong.economics.cornell.edu/papers/Testing%20for%20the%20Markov%20Property%20in%20Time%20Series.pdf) article explains a theoretical point of view but I don't how can I implement it.

Comment: Quick googling on "how to test markov property" returns [this](https://hong.economics.cornell.edu/papers/Testing%20for%20the%20Markov%20Property%20in%20Time%20Series.pdf) as the first result.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 I saw it, but I want to know about practical methods. I edited the post.

Comment: The linked article defines clearly a statistic $\hat{M}$ in equation (2.19) that tests the Markovian null---it is even asymptotically normal under the null, as stated very clearly.